# Mapping Spherical Coordinates

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates

```
Spherical coordinates are in the form (ρ, Θ, φ) 


How are these coordinates mapped when changed to (ρ, Θ, π-φ)?

Circle/Fill In: There is a (reflection/rotation) about the __________ plane
```

I tried to google similar questions, but did not find anything. Is there a name for these kinds of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi$ traces the angle from the north pole to the south. What does $\pi-\phi$ then do? It reverses direction, starting from $\pi$ and ending up at $0$. Thus, it starts at the south pole and ends up at the north.

Can you see now it is whatever your first coordinate was reflected across the $xy$ plane?